# angularjs and jquery performance on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm creating a single page view website with AngularJs and jQuery intended for iPads and other tablets. I used AngularJs because it was requested by our client, but not knowing the AngularJs philosophy I decided to control click events with jQuery (big mistake, I know).

The thing is, mixing the two libraries together this way seems like it causes a lot of **performance issues on mobile devices**. I need to load and manipulate with animations hundreds of divs simultaneously (it's a POS app), and **I was wondering if implementing directives instead of using jQuery events would give me a performance boost**. If not, I really don't see the reason why I should develop directives.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to use css in stead of javascript for animation wherever you can. Also, angular and jquery sounds like overkill for a single-page app. Are you sure you need it? If not, why don't you tell the guys who said "We shall use Angular for all the things" that it is a bad idea?

Comment: I think directives can help you.. The fact that can you isolate your controls and possible issue also will let you improvement them individually.

Comment: Angular itself is quite heavy. I don't know it very well, but I wouldn't expect it to run smoothly on mobile device. Specifically, $watches need to reevaluate and deep-copy watched value on each user action that touches the $scope, which often generates a lot of unnecessary computation.  Also, animations themselves may be a problem. Using css may help a bit.

Comment: @Dalorzo: Appreciation? You probably meant something different, I can't really find _appreciation_ in my comment. Anyway, I agree with you, that using directives can help. I'm just not convinced, if that will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @Frax what I meant is that I do not think angular "heaviness" is the direct responsible of performance issues in our applications but instead how use Angular. I agree that abusing of $watch functions can be harmful but are some other very good parts in angular and can help improve performance a different way.

Comment: Thanks @Cort3z, I'm using css3 translations now and the app runs a lot smoother. But I'm also going to try and develop directives for certain parts of the page so thx Dalorzo and Frax.

Comment: @DavidGonzalezShannon Glad I could help! It's quite interesting topic actually because CSS, on modern browsers at least, actually knows how to do animations in hardware. JS, to my knowledge, can't do that for safety reasons (you can easily crash a computer if you have access to the gpu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I improved the problem thanks to a few things. First, reducing the number of angular elements greatly increases performance. Second, I used [jquery-animate-enhanced](https://github.com/benbarnett/jQuery-Animate-Enhanced) for my movement animations, which also improves translations a lot! Third I used [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for my fade animations, which is great.

I'm still trying to improve performance with view recycling kind of like in iOS or Android, but I'm finding that ng-repeat isn't very happy with that. So, I'm probably going to have to implement directives.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Improve performance :

I have been through this situation and the best thing I did to improve the performance of my SPA web-app is to use native Javascript wherever possible instead of jQuery.

For example, I replaced my

`$(element).html("This is some text")` to `element.innerHTML="This is some text"`

and

`$(document).on('scroll',element,callbackFuntions)` 
to `element.addEventListener('scroll',callbackFunction,{passive:true})`

Notice the **`{passive:true}`** parameter in my scroll even listener, **Passing this, incredibly increased my scrolling experience** and helped me get rid of the scroll-lags.

Reason to use Directive:

There might be times when you want to run a script when the particular element is created in the dom and not before it. That's when directives help a lot.